# Core Data + CloudKit not refreshing on other device automatically?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

I have my SwiftUI app working with Core Data + CloudKit. I am able to save new entries to the database from my Mac or iPhone. The app uses the exact same project/codebase for all devices.

The only problem is that I need to close out of the app and re-open it to see any new entries made from the other device. I can immediately see the new entries made from the same device, but they do not appear on the other devices until I close and re-open the app on it.

Am I missing something here? Do I need to add something like ObservableObject or Identifiable to my Entity class? How do I correct this issue?

**Edit:**

Here is how I obtain the records:

```
@FetchRequest(
    entity: Doc.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]
) var docs: FetchedResults<Doc>
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out!

I had to add:

```
context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
```

To the `scene()` function in `SceneDelegate`:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
```

Now its working flawlessly.

Credit: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/blog/ios-development/data-persistence/getting-started-with-nspersistentcloudkitcontainer/