# How to automatically reflect CoreData+iCloud Changes in SwiftUI view?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, icloud, nsfetchrequest

**So**...I have an app with StoreData and iCloud enabled. My data is syncing between the devices but I don't ge the behaviour I want when it comes to reflecting the changes in the UI.

**The behaviour I want:** When a user has my app open on two devices (A & B) and makes a change one one (A) of them I want the change to automatically reflect in the second (B) device UI within some reasonable time.

[image]

**The behaviour I currently have:** When the user makes changes on one device (A) nothing ever happens on the other (B)...until I minimise and maximise the app on the second device (B) (*Not restarting...just minimising*).

[image]

My thought are that the app won't receive the changes (iCloud won't sync) until some action is triggered when  minimising and reopening the app.

But I don't know. According to [Syncing a Core Data Store with CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/syncing_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit) syncing and notifying other devices should happened automatically. And I think my View should be hooked up correctly as it will change instantly when making local changes to data in the CoreData database.

**My SwiftUI view pretty much looks like this:**

```
import SwiftUI
import CloudKit
import Foundation

struct MyView: View {
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Entity.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Entity>) var entities: FetchedResults<Entity>

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(entities, id: \.id) { e in
                Text("\(e.title)")
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Entity: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var title: String
}
```

**Any Help is much appreciated!**
*(Let me know if I need to provide additional information.)*

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58860967/core-data-cloudkit-not-refreshing-on-other-device-automatically

Comment: @AlbertoLunardini sadly I already have "context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true" and It does not make any difference.

Comment: Do you by any chance use a simulator and a real device to test? I have found that the simulator does not update when you make a change on the real device, but the real device will update when you make a change on the simulator (XCode 11.4).

Comment: @Charles I am using an iPhoneX and an iPad Pro. Both running 13.4

Comment: I see. And have you also tried `try? context.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)`. For every time you access the context, not just once?

Comment: @Charles to my understanding `try? context.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)` should only be used to pin some current state of CoreData to prevent the view from loading CoreData changes (source: [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/accessing_data_when_the_store_has_changed)). Currently I don't use `try? context.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)` anywhere in my code.

Comment: @Charles actually, I have done some more basic testing and I think it all has to do with iCloud not syncing until I minimise the app. 

Because if I do: 
1. perform a change on one device and then don't touch them for a couple minutes (enough time for iCloud to be able to sync)
2. After waiting: Put the other device in flight mode, then minimise the app and reopen. Then no changes will be performed at all until I turn off flight mode. Though even with this knowledge I'm still not sure how I should go on to achieve the behaviour I want.

Comment: It looks like the UI is not reacting to a change of history, which `context.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)` might trigger. I empathise with your problem, I had almost exactly the same last week, and I pulled my hair out for days. My issue was that I did not modify the `viewcontext` in one single but crucial case.

Comment: Does it work now? I have the same problem!

Answer (score 2):

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "ComCloudSync")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

Try adding the following code (change "ComCloudSync" to your appName):

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "ComCloudSync")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })

    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy

  return container
}()
```

Comment: thanks this helped! BUT why is it pointing only to the Private database?

i tried `storeDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions?.databaseScope = .public` in my Presistence.swift file but this didnt work